# command prompt freezed after enabling UFW (Ubuntu 18.04 server)

Tags: command-line, server, freeze, firewall, ufw

After enabling UFW on my server the command prompt freezed, meaning when I typed anything I couldn't see the input.
I then opened another terminal window and connected to the server with no problem. However I am wondering what could have caused such an issue ?
These were commands I typed after which it got freezed.

```
root@ns3247177:~# ufw status
Status: inactive
root@ns3247177:~# ufw enable
Command may disrupt existing ssh connections. Proceed with operation (y|n)? y
Firewall is active and enabled on system startup
root@ns3247177:~#
```

I kept that freezed window open and after a while I got this message :

```
root@ns3247177:~# packet_write_wait: Connection to 164.132.xxx.xxx port 59674: Broken pipe
```

Comment: A “broken pipe” means that you were disconnected from the server. This would have happened when you enabled the firewall because all connections would have been redirected. It’s a consequence of changing network settings while connected over a network.

Comment: I mean, it says right there, "Command may disrupt existing ssh connections." you responded yes to this line.

Comment: Thank you Matigo. 

Levente, yes that's kind of obvious but isn't it strange that such an operation would freeze the command prompt ? I mean developers or whoever are  responsible how the ufw works should have corrected this issue. Just my opinion.

Comment: It is SSH that is causing the freeze since it is waiting for the connection to timeout.  You might want to try setting a connect timeout to see if that makes it return the prompt faster.  This has nothing to do with UFW other than it closing your port that SSH is using promptly, so SSH is trying to reconnect, then it just times out.  That is why you are hanging.  Try:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/377956/is-there-a-way-for-setting-a-shorter-timeout-in-an-ssh-command

Comment: Appreciate your response Terrance.